# Wireshark can see outside of the virtual machine?

Tags: macos, windows-xp, networking, virtual-machine, wireshark

I'm running Windows in a VM inside of OSX. If I start Wireshark inside Windows, then a message from OSX pops up saying that Wireshark is trying to monitor all network traffic. If I accept, then Wireshark starts showing all sorts of network activity. This can't be from Windows, because I don't have anything in there doing anything, but I am running things which are communicating through the internet in OSX.

Is Wireshark able to see the network activity from OSX? How can it do this if it's inside a virtual machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other people have provided good answers, but it looks like nobody answered this part:

```
How can it do this if it's inside a virtual machine?
```

In "bridged" mode, VMWare is giving the guest low-level access to the network interface. This is potentially an unsafe privilege to give to the guest, since it could spy on the host's network activity or even on other hosts on the same network.

That's why VMWare warns you about "attempting to monitor traffic" -- VMWare is confirming with you that it's okay to provide this privilege to the guest.

Answer (score 4):

Most commercial VM managers default to shared networking, which allows the VM to share all of the host's network interfaces, or bridged networking, which allows the VM to share a particular host network interface.  To restrict this, switch the VM to "host-only" networking; you will then have to use some kind of NAT arrangement for the VM to communicate with the outside world.

Comment: Will there be any difference seen by Wireshark between shared and bridged networking?

Comment: @OSX Jedi: Try it and ... see?

Comment: Shared will see all host interfaces' traffic on the virtual `eth0`; bridged only sees activity from the bridged interface, and host-only will only see traffic over the virtual tunnel gateway (`vnic0` on the host side here, with Parallels)

Comment: For spying on the network is shared better than bridged mode?

Comment: Depends on where you want to spy.  If I have multiple interfaces and  want to see traffic only on one of them inside the VM, I would have to use bridged instead of shared.

Answer (score 2):

The virtual machine's network settings are likely in bridged mode, meaning it receives a routable IP address on your LAN just like the Mac itself. With this setting, promiscuous mode in Wireshark can see exactly what your Mac workstation sees. Host Only or Internal networking will hide outside traffic.